# If/then not matching

Tags: powershell

The PS script assigns two variables and checks to see if they match - no brainer.

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "ddd"   # Get today in 3 chars
$str_SwitchDay = "Wed"            # The day of week when I have to switch/increment $counter

if ([string]$Today -eq [string]$str_SwitchDay) {
    # Increment week number
    $Counter = [int]$Counter++
    if ($Counter -ge 5) {
        $Counter = 1
        }
```

When I check the Length of both strings its 3, when I output the data to a text file they both say Wed.  I must be missing something very basic here surely

I have a very verbose log file that keeps track of progress of the script (and to help debug)
I added the [string] syntax before each to make sure I was comparing strings and not string to object

Comment: When the code is live I set $str_SwitchDay to Mon.  When coding i set it to the day I am working on it (today it is Wed here in .AU)

Answer (score 4):

> `$Counter = [int]$Counter++`

This *never increments* the value stored in variable `$Counter`.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, use `++$Counter`  - while this works even if `$Counter` wasn't previously defined, for robustness it's best to initialize it with `$Counter = 0` (data type `[int]` is implied).

---

Aside from that:

It's better to work with [`[datetime]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.DateTime) directly instead of *string representations* of dates or date parts.

Keeping that in mind, you can restructure your code as follows:

```
$Today = Get-Date
$switchDay = [System.DayOfWeek]::Wednesday

if ($Today.DayOfWeek -eq $switchDay) {
    if (++$Counter -ge 5) {
      $Counter = 1
    }
```

---

<sup>[1] You're using the *post*-increment form of the `++` operator, which uses the *original* value of `$Counter` in the expression, and *then* increments. However, the fact that you're *explicitly assigning back to `$Counter`* overrides the increment, so that your assignment is in effect the same as `$Counter = [int] $Counter`.  While `$Counter = [int]++$Counter`, i.e. the *pre*-increment form of `++`, *would* work, there's no reason to use it, given that `++$Counter` *alone* has the same effect: even if variable `$Counter` wasn't previously defined, the increment operation makes it default to `[int] 0` before incrementing.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I think that the first if statement is fine. The if statement does see the two strings as equal. For testing I removed your content and just display one of the variables.
I copy/pasted the rest of your script and this worked for me:

```
$Today = Get-Date -Format "ddd"   # Get today in 3 chars
$str_SwitchDay = "Wed"            # The day of week when I have to switch/increment $counter

if ([string]$Today -eq [string]$str_SwitchDay) {
  echo "str switchday : $str_SwitchDay"
}
```

If you are having another problem then please be more specific in your question.

Comment: If you believe that the code in the question doesn't result in the claimed symptom, it's best to note that _in a comment_, and ask that the question be amended as part of that comment.

Comment: When I switched the variable assignment from  $Today = Get-Date -Format "ddd
 to $Today = (Get-Date).DayOfWeek.ToString() it suddenly began to see them as the same...not sure why.  Thanks for the headsup on clarity too

Comment: @mklement0 I did try that but I also wanted to post easily testable working example code which I couldn't do in a comment

Comment: @askitee, that's not plausible, because, on Wednesdays, `(Get-Date).DayOfWeek.ToString()` is `"Wednesday"`, not `"Wed"`, so comparing it to the latter is always `$false`. In fact, the very point of this answer was to demonstrate that there is _no_ problem with the comparison part of your code. By contrast, the other answer points out an actual problem with your code.

Comment: @SchwarzSoftware, pointing out that `(Get-Date -Format "ddd") -eq "Wed"` is true on Wednesdays in a comment would have sufficed.